# How to uninstall sensei format?

Tags: interface, add-on, theme

I saw a tutorial on youtube that told something about the sensei format. I was totally unknown to this and wanted to try out what it was. So, I downloaded the addon and installed it, but when I wanted to remove it it won't go. So, I completely uninstalled blender, deleted the whole of the sensei format, even the zip file on my desktop, checked the c drive. And then reinstalled blender from the backup file that I had on my E: and installed it again but When I opened up the file this is the UI:
[image: first image]
So getting no way out of it, I just loaded the factory setting and hit CTRL + U, in hope to find that the UI would be the same the next time I open blender, only to be disappointed that the UI is still as above, which was supposed to be like the default like this:
[image: second image]
I search through the user preferences to see if the addon was there but it isn't there anymore however blender still remembers it.
**How can I revert the changes that I made by my big mistake of installing the sensei format addon?**

Comment: have you checked in \AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation ?

Comment: Have you looked at themes in the user preferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides the Theme I cannot see any difference, so let's fix that.

1. hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to open User Preferences.
2. Go to the "Themes" panel and look at "Presets". Select "Sensei", if it's not there.
3. Hit the "-" button to get rid of it.
4. Hit "Restore to Default Theme"
5. Hit "Save User Settings"

[image]

Comment: thank you very very much, I didn't realize it was the theme.